# React TypeScript: Alternatives to UseRef in functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there another way of getting/setting the values from the dom that is less expensive than useRef()? Is useRef() to be used lightly as the docs suggest?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Join: React.FC = () => {

  const fullName = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const email = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const password = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const myForm = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myForm.current) myForm.current.reset();
    if (fullName.current) fullName.current.focus();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div>
      <form ref={myForm}>
       <input type='text' ref={fullName} />
       <input type='text' ref={email} />
       <input type='text' ref={password} />
      </form>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: Chaging a ref won't trigger another render. Usually it is a bad idea to access methods like `focus`. What are you trying to acomplish with this code? Please take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Still its not clear, why you used useRef, can you give more info?

Comment: When the component loads I want to clear the form and focus the fullName input

Comment: what I have now works, but is this the "right way'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the component loads I want to clear the form and focus the
>   fullName input

You don't need `refs` for that

**I want to clear the form**

- Make your `inputs` [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)
- Declare an empty string as initial value

---

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        email : '',
        password : ''
    })

    const onChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) =>{
        setState(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            [name] : value
        }))
    } 

    const { email, password } = state
    return(
        <>
            <input value={email} onChange={onChange} id='email'/>
            <input value={password} onChange={onChange} id='password' />
        </>
    )
}
```

**Automatically focus a given input**

Just use `autofocus` for that

```
<input autofocus/>
```

Comment: `value={email}` should this not be `value={state.email}` ??

Comment: I can see that onChange is updating the state, but how does the form get cleared?

Comment: I've destructured `email` and `password` from `state` so i don't have to type `state.email`. Now to clear the form is just setting the state as the initial. `state = ''` `pass = ''`